# The best way to save game score ranking by UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I often make game apps which save game score and show their ranking like the below. (It never uses any server. User can check their own game score in app.)

```
rank   level  score
1st  level 99 9999
2nd  level 87 8875
3rd  level 87 8875
4th  level 64 6938
5th  level 3  320
...
```

When I implement the ranking like that, I always use multidimensional array like the below.

```
rankArray
level score 
[0]   [0]   //1st
[1]   [1]   //2nd
[2]   [2]   //3rd

//[0] = 99, 9999
//[1] = 87, 8875
```

But if you know the better way to save ranking, please tell me about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try storing the user scores using `CoreData`.

Create a `Score` object with `level` and `scoreValue` as the properties.

This way the data is persisted and can easily be sorted and filtered multiple ways.

You can save all scores and fetch the the top ones, or manage which scores to save and always fetch all.

Once you fetch the top scores, order the `scoreValues` descending to sort them by rank.

[CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html) is a pretty powerful freebie

Comment: Should not `rank` calculate at run time as it depends on other user's scores?

Comment: @TheTiger, actually, you saying that made me realize that `rank` shouldn't be a stored property at all. When you fetch the top scores, you would sort them high-to-low, which would be "ranking" them. Thanks for mentioning that, I'll update my answer :)

Comment: @TheTiger, and to answer your question based on the update, the rankings would only be calculated when the scores were fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use linked chain list which is the most suitable data structure.
It allows you a fast insertion of an element wherever its position.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it with UserDefaults, you can do it as following:

```
    var rank = [Int:[String:Int]]()

    rank[1] = ["level" : 1,
               "score" : 99]

    rank[2] = ["level" : 30,
               "score" : 89]

    let gameData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: rank)

    UserDefaults.standard .set(gameData, forKey: "score")

    let dataFromUserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard .value(forKey: "score")
    let retrievedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dataFromUserDefaults as! Data) as? [Int:[String:Int]]
```